# iPhone Settings Menu - creating a list that allows user to add, edit and delete items

Tags: iphone, settings

I am looking to create a settings menu feature that allows users to add, edit and remove items from a list. In adding an item to the list, the user will then be prompted to add some further sub-data such as name, value etc. The list should only allow one item to be selected. As far as I can see this is similar to, but beyond the capability of the PSMultiValueSpecifier, in terms of the user adds/edits/deletes and sub-data being added.

Similar functionality is implemented in the ‘Choose A Network’ section of the iPhone’s Wi-Fi settings but I am not sure how this is done. In this, users can add a new network and then specify security type, password etc.

Any ideas how I might go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Do a search in sample code regarding UITableView (In iPhone dev center or inside Documentation), I am sure I have seen that kind of sample ;)